# Sendind http json request from AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask, httprequest, android-volley, sendasynchronousrequest

Here is small example for to understand my question:

```
public class InitSettings_Task extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Integer>  {
  @Override
  protected Integer doInBackground(Void... params) {
    request1result = request1;
    if (request1result) {
      result = httprequest2;
    } else {
      result = httprequest3;
    }  

    return result;
  }

  @Override
  protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {
    //do something with result
  }
}
```

I know that Volley is a super library, but here i can't use it because my AsyncTask can ends before i will receive answer of first request.

Can somebody help me to understand what the best style for to send http request for this logic?

Before i have used Volley with Sleep() for to wait answer, but from my view it's not best sollution

Comment: you should use some non async http client fx.: URLConnection or some http library which allows non async request like okhttp

Comment: Thanks, for right direction)

Comment: I fount info about Volley have possibility to do it over RequestFuture. What do you recommend, use Volley or OkHTTP more stable for this kind of task?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are trying to do this -

```
public class InitSettings_Task1 extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Integer>  {
  @Override
  protected Integer doInBackground(Void... params) {
    request1result = request1;


    return result;
  }

  @Override
  protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {
    //do something with result
    if (request1result) {
      result = new InitSettings_Task2().execute(httprequest2);
    } else {
      result = new InitSettings_Task2().execute(httprequest3); 
    }  

  }
}

public class InitSettings_Task2 extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Integer>  {


   @Override
   protected Integer doInBackground(Void... params) {
      return result;
   }

   @Override
   protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {
   //do what you want with result ?  
   }
}
```

But I would advise you against this. Its better to do this using frameworks like RxJava or even EventBus which are better suited for this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

I have realized it with OkHTTP library. Thank's "Selvin" for right direction )